# Object: com.test.ActualEntity is not a known entity type + EclipseLink and Wildfly 10.1.0

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, wildfly-10

I am getting this exception mentioned below while persisiting an entity in eclipselink. App Server used is Wildfly 10.1.0 Final

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: com.test.ActualEntity@7338353f is not a known entity type.

Persistence.xml contains the fully qualified class name

```
 <persistence-unit name="TestDomain"> 
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/TEST_DB_SAMPLE</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.test.ActualEntity</class>
    <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="username"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxxx"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="DefaultLogger"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

@Entity is mentioned at class level

@Id is GeneratedType.IDENTITY

DB : MySQL

Error log as below

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: com.test.ActualEntity@7338353f is not a known entity type.
2018-07-14 00:31:38,200 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4228)
```

This happens only after login is successful.
if I disable login all other entities are recognized.

Any help will be apprciated

Regards,

Dwaipayan

Comment: What do you mean all other entities are recognized if you disable login - what is login, and what other entities are there?  Turn on EclipseLink logging to finest to see what is getting loaded in this persistence unit - looks like a class loader issue.

Comment: How is EclipseLink installed?